# How to enable curl in php 7.3+ in uwamp server

Tags: php, windows, curl, uwamp

I'm running Uwamp server under windows7 and it works perfectly with php versions from 5.5 to 7.0.3 and with curl enabled. 
When I switch to php 7.2, 7.3 or latest 7.4.3 uwamp server still working - but without curl.

php_curl.dll file is enabled under extensions (ext) but phpinfo() confirms that curl extension is missing / not enabled. I compared php.ini with previous php versions, modified it but it still doesn't work.

> cURL is NOT installed on this server

I have testet xampp and this server has no problem with curl and php 7.3/7.4. I compared php.ini etc. but curl extension still not working under Uwamp.

It seems that the author of the project has abandoned it, because there have been no updates or activities since many years. Maybe someone using it and can help me to solve it.
Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

finally got a working solution for this problem of uwamp and running an up to date version of php and getting curl working.

I have sat here for a couple of days trying to work why you couldn't get a later version of php 7.0.3 without breaking uwamp and curl. So I learnt how to integrate and test php apache as standalones and then working on updating uwamp. Lots of head scratching of working out how uwamp uses its on the fly configuration setup.

I will list all the steps to update your version of uwamp (to apache 4.2 and php 7.4.4 as of Mar 2020)

1. Download uwamp (portable or installer)
2. Download c++ runtime  https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x86.exe (taken from the windows php page)
3. Install the runtime above
4. Install uwamp to a directory (in this example will just use c:\ making it install to c:\uwamp after expanding)

Before running uwamp

1. Goto to apache lounge website and download the latest 32 build of apache (4.2)
   https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VS16/binaries/httpd-2.4.41-win32-VS16.zip
2. Expand this archive, it should create a folder called apache2.4
3. Step in to this directory and copy all the files and paste them here in your uwamp folder (c:\uwamp\bin\apache). This should overwrite all the apache files and add the latest apachephp dll

TIP. Just make sure you havent expanded the apache2.4 zip in the uwamp apache folder, easy to tell as you will see a apache24 appear

1. Goto to php.net and download the latest THREAD SAFE version of php (7.4.4)
   https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.4.4-Win32-vc15-x86.zip
2. Extract the php zip this folder in to the c:\uwamp\bin\php in to a new folder with name of php-7.4.4 (so the files should be in c:\uwamp\bin\php\php-7.4.4)

There you are, you have completed your manual upgrade of uwamp , run uwamp and if no errors appear with in the GUI, everything should be working. Test by opening a browser and use http://localhost/uwamp/phpinfo or http://127.0.0.1/uwamp/phpinfo or click the "phpinfo button" in the uwamp GUI

This way seems to allowed an upgrade of uwamp (except sql) but resolve a common problem of php and curl not working / breaking.

This works for x86 version installed on a 32/64 bit system. 
Still trying to work out the kinks for uwamp to be running 64 bit apache and php but should be possible.

Comment: Thanks!  I have done this and get path errors in httpd.conf file, line 171 loading LoadModule php_module.  I backed up my old apache folder and copied over the old apache folder.  When that gave me errors, I tried copying the original conf folder contents over the new ones, but the path errors have persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Try and delete the version of PHP that is affected by the missing Curl extension and then re-download the version from inside the AWamp interface. I have had similar problems with other extensions and have solved it this way.